# How to enter input in function calls in c++ when comparing strings

Tags: c++

My code is given below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class object
{
public:
    string s;
    int a;
    void add()
    {
        cout << "enter name and speed:" << endl;
        cin >> s;
        cin >> a;
        cout << "done" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    object o[10];
    string line;
    string a[10];
    // grab a line from standard input
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        // break the input in to tokens using a space as the delimeter
        istringstream stream(line);
        string token;
        while (getline(stream, token, ' '))
        {
            // convert string to all caps
            // transform(token.begin(), token.end(), token.begin(), (int(*)(int)) toupper);
            a[i++] = token;
            // print each token on a separate line
            cout << endl << token << endl;
        }
    }
    if (a[0].compare("make") == 0)
    {    
        if (a[1].compare("fan") == 0)
        {
            o[0].add();
            cout << "lol" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

> make
>   fan
>   enter name and speed:
>   done
>   lol

The problem is I can't enter the values of `name` and `speed`. It is skipping them and printing `done` and `lol`. Please tell me how to enter the values of `name` and `speed`.

Given below is the text file.

> make fan 5
>      make a.c 4

Comment: Its no use.The terminal is not asking for the values of 'name' and 'speed'.Its skipping them.

Comment: Add this inside `add()` above the two extractions: `std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: the problem is that the program is reading the whole file in the first while loop and it does not read the second time inside the add function.Can anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that you can give us a [demo](http://ideone.com) of the program behaving as you describe?

Comment: Please run the above code as follows:1.g++ filename.cpp  2../a.out<file.txt .You will get the output as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never leave the first while

May be It should be some thing like this ?

```
while (getline(cin, line)) {

// break the input in to tokens using a space as the delimeter
istringstream stream(line);
string token;
bool flag=false;
while (getline(stream, token,' ')) {

    // convert string to all caps
    //transform(token.begin(), token.end(), token.begin(), (int(*)(int)) toupper);
    a[i++]=token;
    if(i==10)
        flag=true;
    // print each token on a separate line
    cout <<'\n'<< token << '\n';
}
if(flag)
    break;
```

}

Comment: I think the problem is in add() function but can't figure it.At the declaration of "String line",if it is initialised,then the program is asking for 'name' and 'speed' at the add function.But if the input is given as  a file,there is a problem.Can anyone please explain where the problem is?